# How to add a dvi tag to a shortcode then change a generated text using jQuery

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, jquery, css

I have a plugin that generates tables based on mysql queries.
The plugin generated a shortcode that I put in posts to show the tables.

Above the table there is a button that has a span. the span text is `Columns`.

I want to change the text from `Columns` to `This is my new Text`.  There is no way to do this in the plugin options and I contacted the developer who confirmed this.

I inspected the button and obtained its class, then I used the following jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery(".buttons-collection.buttons-colvis.DTTT_button.DTTT_button_colvis span ").text(" This is My New Text ");
});
</script>
```

The code works fine, except that it changes the text of that button in all the tables, which is something I don't want. I want to change the text on some buttons only, based on the content of the table.

I tried putting the shortcode inside a div tag like this:

```
<div class="new-class">[plugin shortcode]</div>
```

Then I added the class to the jQyery like this:

```
jQuery(".new-class.buttons-collection.buttons-colvis.DTTT_button.DTTT_button_colvis span ").text(" This is My New Text ");
```

But it did not work. It showed the default text `Columns`.

I think that the problem is that the classes in the code that worked are classes of the button itself, while I added a class to the whole table?

Any idea what is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shortcode should add a unique id and not only a class. This can be an explicit id attribute (best) or by generating some random id. Now when outputting the shortcode you add a JS which uses specific selection based on the id.

Comment: it adds an id for the whole table, not the button, and this id is changeable based on how many tables are in the page. so If i changed the page structure, the id changes. That's what the developer told me. [Here is a link to a test page](https://coptic-treasures.com/wp/bible-trial-001/). the button now has "This is my new text". I can't find a unique id for the button. Thanks

Comment: if it is not your code, then you need to ask the author to change the behaviour

Comment: .... or you need to wrap it with your div.... write a shortcode that wraps the current one to do this